# Python Pandas: Index a value and boolean comparison

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this dataframe:

```
index = pd.Index(list(range(5)), name='rows')
columns = pd.Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], name='cols')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), index=index, columns=columns)
if df.A[-1:] < df.B[-1:] and df.B[-1:] > df.C[-1:] :
    print True
```

Here, I'm trying to compare two values not two arrays, but pandas generates this value error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Am I wrong with slicing? How to slice two values and compare them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) with last item of columns by `[-1]` for comparing `values`:

```
if (df.A.iloc[-1] < df.B.iloc[-1]) & (df.B.iloc[-1] > df.C.iloc[-1]):
    True
```

You can try add [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) for comparing `Series`:

```
if (df.A[-1:] < df.B[-1:]).all() & (df.B[-1:] > df.C[-1:]).all():
    True
```

Or [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for comparing `numpy arrays`:

```
if ((df.A[-1:] < df.B[-1:]).values) & ((df.B[-1:] > df.C[-1:]).values):
    True
```

Or:

```
if (df.A[-1:].values < df.B[-1:].values) & (df.B[-1:].values > df.C[-1:].values):
    True
```

Explanation:

```
#return Series
print df.A[-1:]
rows
4    0.251539
Name: A, dtype: float64

#return numpy array 
print df.A[-1:].values
[ 0.25153871]

#return value
print df.A.iloc[-1]
0.251538705128
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.A[-1:]` selects a range of the last item to the end, you want just `df.A[-1]`.